# How to update the forgotpassword by sending an email in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, email

Hi I have a registration form if I click on forgot password I am getting mail if I click on that link it is redirecting to changepassword page here I am not able to update the password for a particular user. Here is my code.Is it possible to send confirmcode in hidden value while sending forgot password mail

Sending mail:From this code I will be getting email.

```
$email=$_POST['email'];

if($_POST['submit']=='Send')

{

$query="select * from registered where email='$email'"; 

$result=mysql_query($query) or die(error);

if(mysql_num_rows($result))

{

$to = $_POST['email'];

$from .= 'mail@gmail.com' . "\r\n\r\n";

$subject="Password Change link here";

$message.="Click on this link to change your password \r\n";

$message.="http://website.com/accounting/changepassword.php?email=$email";

$success = mail($to, $subject, $message);

echo "Forgot Password link has been sent to your email.Check your email to change your password";

}

else

{

echo "No user exist with this email id";

}

}

link: Click on this link to change your password
http://website.com/accounting/changepassword.php?email=mail@gmail.com
```

If I click on that link it will redirect to `forgetten.php` page and my code is

But I am not able to update the password can anyone help me this. If i click on that link it will redirect to this page from here it will changepassword.php

Changepassword.php

```
<form method="POST" action="forgotten.php" id="myform">
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>" name='email'>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon"></span> Password</label>
<input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password here" required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="rpsw"><span class="glyphicon"></span>Confirm Password</label>
<input id="repassword" class="form-control" type="password" name="repassword" placeholder="Retype password here" required/>
</div>
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Create New Password</button>
```

forgetten.php code:

```
    <?php

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "account") or       die(mysql_error());

  $db = mysql_select_db("accounting", $connection);

  $email=$_POST['email'];

  $password=$_POST['password'];

  $repassword=$_POST['repassword'];

  $sql1="SELECT * FROM registered WHERE email ='$email'";

  $result1=mysql_query($sql1);

  $query = mysql_query("update registered SET password = '$password', repassword ='$repassword' WHERE email='$email'");

 if($query)

 {

 $to = $_POST['email'];

 $from .= 'mail@gmail.com' . "\r\n\r\n";

 $subject="Password Changed";

 $message.="your password has been changed successfully. \r\n";     

 $success = mail($to, $subject, $message);

 echo "Password has been changed successfully";

 }

    else{
        echo "Insertion Falied";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**changepassword.php**

1. Replace `AND` with `,` between `password` & `repassword`.
2. Remove `'` in coloumn name `email`.
3. Change `'email'=$result1` to `email='$email'`

Change

```
$query = mysql_query("update registered SET password = '$password' AND repassword ='$repassword' WHERE 'email'=$result1");
```

to

```
$query = mysql_query("update registered SET password = '$password', repassword ='$repassword' WHERE email='$email'");
```

**For User's Requirement.**

Since, you are passing email to `changepassword.php`. 
You have to create one `hidden field` for `email`, which will get submitted to **forgottenpassword.php** page.

Check your database connection. And, cross check whether all column name are written properly.

Use this code as it is.

**ChangePassword.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="forgotten.php" id="myform">
    <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>" name='email'>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon"></span> Password</label>
    <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password here" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="rpsw"><span class="glyphicon"></span>Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="repassword" class="form-control" type="password" name="repassword" placeholder="Retype password here" required/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Create New Password</button>
</form>
```

**forgotten.php**

```
<?
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("db_name", $connection);

$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$repassword=$_POST['repassword']; 

$sql1="SELECT * FROM registered WHERE email ='$email'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

$query = mysql_query("update registered SET password = '$password', repassword ='$repassword' WHERE email='$email'");

if($query)
{
    $to = $email;
    $from = 'mail@gmail.com';
    $subject="Password Changed";
    $message.="your password has been changed successfully. ";      
    $success = mail($to, $subject, $message);
    echo "Password has been changed successfully";
}
?>
```

Comment: No it is not working and not displaying any success or failure message

Comment: Hi @Nagu, Very first thing, it is going to **changepassword.php** page. Where you are filling/inserting `password` and `repassword` value. After that it is coming to any **submit page**. Where is your code for that `<form>`?

Comment: I just corrected your error. Which was present in your query. If it is not displaying success message or else, there is error in your code then. To rectify, you have to provide code for `<form>` also. Then, only we can find the exact problem. Update your question with `<form>` code @Nagu

Comment: <form method= "post" action="forgotten.php" id="myform">
 <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon"></span> Password</label>
  <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Enter password here" required/>
<label for="rpsw"><span class="glyphicon"></span>Confirm Password</label>
 <input id="repassword" class="form-control" type="password" name="repassword" value="" placeholder="Retype password here" required/>
<button type="submit" >Create New Password</button>
 </form>

Comment: Then, where you are filling password and repassword textbox value. There is <form> right ? Where is that code @Nagu

Comment: changepassword.php is my code from where i need to update the code

Comment: Why you are not understanding @Nagu ? In simple word, `<input type='textbox' name='password'>`. Where is this code present. Show us that code.

Comment: Yess @Nagu. Wait for my answer.

Comment: Check my answer @Nagu. And, respond me back.

Comment: ya sure i will check it

Comment: Both Page. ChangePassword & ForgottenPassword Page @Nagu

Comment: Is your database name is 'db_name' @Nagu

Comment: my database name is registered.I have copied only query and post method for  email thats it

Comment: Are you sure ? And, table name also 'registered'. Have you wrote your database name in `$db = mysql_select_db("registered", $connection);` I already told you to check your database connection and cross check all coulmn name and table name. First check that @Nagu

Comment: Ya my database name accountant i have done that and table name is registered

Comment: First you told registered. and, now you are telling acountant. You did something wrong. I'm sure. Now, Again one task for you. Please update your question with your updated code of changepassword.php and forgotten.php . I would like to see it. We are close to it. @Nagu

Comment: Connections,database name ,column names all are correct

Comment: i thought you are asking about table name so i said table name

Comment: No Problem @Nagu. Please update your question with the updated code. I want to see it. Both Page OK. And, respond me back.

Comment: I have updated the code changepassword.php and forgetten.php whats its happening means if i click on create new password it is not displaying either success or failure message

Comment: Ok @Nagu. Tell me one thing. Is it updating value now in database table. I figuring out the issue.

Comment: No it is not updating in database

Comment: If i console the code then in hidden value it is passing the email id

Comment: `$query = mysql_query("update registered SET password = '$password', repassword ='$repassword' WHERE email='$email'");`
Just below this line. 
write `echo "update registered SET password = '$password', repassword ='$repassword' WHERE email='$email'"; die;`

and show me the output @Nagu

Comment: It is not going to forgotten.php page at all

Comment: If you think, this answer helped you. Please mark this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find it easily. @Nagu Thanks.

Comment: @NanaPartykar `if($query)` for the UPDATE, is best to use `mysql_affected_rows()` for real truthness ;-)

Comment: Yeah @Fred-ii-. But, I didn't paid attention to `mysql_affected_rows()`, Just because of confused code. Errors were so many, that i thought to fix it first. :D :) ;) *Happy Makar Sakranti* From India

Comment: @Nagu: Till now you have not ticked answer as correct. User will unnecessary give answer as it is already answered . So, kindly tick this answer as correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

It is working

```
<?php
 $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
 $db = mysql_select_db("db_name", $connection);

 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 $repassword=$_POST['repassword']; 

 $sql1="SELECT * FROM registered WHERE email ='$email'";
 $result1=mysql_query($sql1);

 $query = mysql_query("update registered SET password = '$password', repassword ='$repassword' WHERE email='$email'");

if($query)
{
$to = $email;
$from = 'mail@gmail.com';
$subject="Password Changed";
$message.="your password has been changed successfully. ";      
$success = mail($to, $subject, $message);
echo "Password has been changed successfully";
}
```

?>