# After login in to the profile how to insert some other columns data into same database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a signup form. Once i create a form the data is inserted into registered table once after login the form i need to fill some details and insert into same columns by comparing mail ids. But when I'm trying to insert the data it is showing as not inserted into database.

dashboard.php:

```
 <form method="post" action="personalinfo.php" id="myform">
    <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>" name='email'>     
       <div>
          <label for="first-name">First Name<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
          <input id="first-name"  type="text" name="first-name" value="" />
        </div>   
      <button type="submit" id = "submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Save</button>
```

personalinfo.php:

```
 <?php
 $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
 $db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $firstname = $_POST['first-name'];
 $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registered (first-name) 
values ('$firstname') SELECT email FROM registered WHERE email!='$email'  ");
mysql_query("$query") OR die("Error:".mysql_error());
if($query)
{
    echo "Successfully Registered";        

}
else{
    echo "Registration has not been completed.Please try again";
}
?>
```

If i use mysql_error it is showing as query is empty.

Comment: Your query is wrong, you cannot make a INSERT and SELECT in the same query like that.

Comment: if i use where condition also it is not working instead of the above query$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registered (first-name) 
values ('$firstname')  WHERE email='$email'  ");

Comment: You don't use INSERT with where, use UPDATE instead of INSERT.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do here is to check whether the email has already been registered previously.

In case its not you want to insert new record. If its is already present then you do not want to insert the record. I am afraid my friend the way you are trying to do here will not work for you.

Comment: Just to let you know with PHP7 release mysql* functions have been deprecated. Try updating your database calls to be PDO instead.

Comment: As i tried for update also  but also it is not working                                                           UPDATE registered SET first-name='$firstname',last-name='$lastname ' WHERE email='$email'

Comment: Actually first i will create a account with email,password,confirm password and i will login into the page by using email and password,once i login into the site i need to fill some other details like(first-name,last-name,mobile) and need to be updated in the same table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert some columns of data into a table after login in mysql php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917462/how-to-insert-some-columns-of-data-into-a-table-after-login-in-mysql-php)

Comment: This person is having too many accounts like http://stackoverflow.com/users/5452729/nagu. He never accept any answer. He never reward person for answering his question. One example for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786799/how-to-update-the-forgotpassword-by-sending-an-email-in-mysql-php/34787640#34787640

Comment: Adding to it. He asked same question 3 hours ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917462/how-to-insert-some-columns-of-data-into-a-table-after-login-in-mysql-php. Which is fortunately duplicated.

Comment: Becuase i didnt get correct answer in that actually one of guy has worked for that so for nderstanding purpose i have created new question that unfortunately has become duplicate

Comment: and regarding for not accepting i dont know how to accept the answer is correct so i asked already but no response from anyone so what should i do

Comment: No. Mr. Fred Already told you how to accept an answer. *Please don't lie*. See comment section of this question and tell no one helped you ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786799/how-to-update-the-forgotpassword-by-sending-an-email-in-mysql-php/34787640#34787640

Comment: And, even i reminded you 2-3 times. But, you didn't responded me back. We take our precious time to help. It comes from both the end. We are not greedy of bounty. We feel happy when you people reply "It's Working. Thanks". We are greedy of this comment.

Comment: @nana partykar iam not lying and nothing will come for me if i lie then right he sent some meta link i opened that link and he said to go back until it turns green i did the same now also but iam not finding green mark .y should lie

Comment: *... so i asked already but no response from anyone*. Whom you asked.? I didn't got any notification regarding your question that Mr Nagu is asking something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete set of your answer with comments.

```
<?php 

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);

$email=$_POST['email'];
$firstname = $_POST['first_name'];

// CHECK IF THE EMAIL IS ALREADY REGISTERED PREVIOUSLY
$res = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM registered WHERE email='$email");


if(!$res || mysql_num_rows($res)<1){ // IF NOT THEN ADD THE RECORD

 $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registered (first_name, email) values ('$firstname', '$email')") OR die("Error:".mysql_error());
}else{ // if email already present then update the record
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE registered SET first_name='$firstname'" where email= '$email') OR die("Error:".mysql_error());
}
 if($query)
 { 
    echo "Successfully Registered";        
 }
 else{
    echo "Registration has not been completed.Please try again";
 }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to answer this question that this question has been solved because iam getting problem you helped me a lot thanks for that.

Comment: can you please tell me how to tick this question has been answered like that

Comment: If it is one record then it is inserting correcting but if there are more than one record it is not updating for that record

Answer (score 2):

> after login the form i need to fill some details

As per this line, it means you want to update first name in the same row. You can use this query.

(**Also mentioned in comments and other answer**)

```
UPDATE registered SET first-name = '$firstname' WHERE email = '$email'
```

**Other Issues:**

You have some other issues in your code:

1. Using `mysql_*` extension, its deprecated, please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
2. No need to use query function as `mysql_query("$query")` it should be `mysql_query($query)`;
3. Calling `mysql_query` twice.
4. Code open for SQL Injection.
5. One last thing, and most important, there is no check either form submit or not, if i hit this file directly `personalinfo.php` it will insert empty records in your table.

**Side Note:**

It just a suggestion, please use underscore `(_)` instead of hyphen `(-)` for table or column names.

Comment: This person is having too many accounts like http://stackoverflow.com/users/5452729/nagu. He never accept any answer. He never reward person for answering his question. One example for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786799/how-to-update-the-forgotpassword-by-sending-an-email-in-mysql-php/34787640#34787640

Comment: Adding to it. He asked same question 3 hours ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917462/how-to-insert-some-columns-of-data-into-a-table-after-login-in-mysql-php. Which is fortunately duplicated.

Comment: @NanaPartykar: i dont have any idea about the policies, well, plz paste this comment in question.

Comment: I already did. And, raised flag too. Let moderator do some action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$query = mysql_query("update registered set first-name = '$firstname' where email = '$email'");
```

Comment: You want to set the firstname of a person if the email id matches, right?

Comment: yes if the emailid matches then i have to insert firstname in that table

Comment: I don't understand why its not working. Is there some error? Just echo the query to the page and run the query that is echoed, in phpmyadmin. You can troubleshoot like that.

Comment: $query = "update registered set first-name = '$firstname' where email = '$email'"; echo $query;exit; //Troubleshoot like this. Hope you get the solution soon.

Comment: its not working, becuase OP using mysql_query function twice, and maybe for this mysql_query("$query");

Answer (score 0):

Use your query like this  :

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE registered set first-name = '$firstname'
WHERE email = '$email'");
```

Here this will update first-name value to value of $firtname in row where email is equal to $email value. For more details check this url : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Answer (score 0):

This will serve what you are looking for.

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
 $db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);

 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $firstname = $_POST['first-name'];

 $res = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM registered WHERE email='$email");

 if(!$res || mysql_num_rows($res)<1){
     $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registered (first-name, email) values ('$firstname', '$email')") OR die("Error:".mysql_error());
     // mysql_query("$query") OR die("Error:".mysql_error());
     if($query)
     { 
        echo "Successfully Registered";        

     }
     else{
        echo "Registration has not been completed.Please try again";
     }
 }
```

Comment: I tried this one got this Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-name) values ('name')' at line 1

Comment: okie thank you its working if i use insert query then it is inserting as another row so i made it as update so it is working fine and i have from hypen(-) to underscore (_). Thanks a lot

Comment: Well please provide proper naming and syntax to get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

After login you can insert the data by

```
$query = mysql_query("update registered set first-name = '$firstname' where email = '$email'");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct answer

```
<?php 

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);

$email=$_POST['email'];
$firstname = $_POST['first_name'];

$res = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM registered WHERE email='$email");

if(!$res || mysql_num_rows($res)<1){
 $query = mysql_query("UPDATE registered SET first_name='$firstname'") OR die("Error:".mysql_error());
 // mysql_query("$query") OR die("Error:".mysql_error());
 if($query)
 { 
    echo "Successfully Registered";        
 }
 else{
    echo "Registration has not been completed.Please try again";
 }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here.. this will always update the record but what if there is no registered email atall in the first place

Comment: becuase only the registered user can be able to login in to the site right so

Comment: I thought this was the registration or profile updation page rather than a login page. Your orignal question says its a signup form not a login form.

However check my latest answer below.